# Attribute error when sending json with Requests from mediainfo AWS Lambda

Tags: json, mongodb, aws-lambda, python-requests, mediainfo

I m trying to send video metadata to MongoDB Atlas from an s3 bucket with media info as an AWS Lambda in Python 3.7. It works when I hardcode the data, but I receive either an object key error or an attribute error. I tried importing json and using json.loads() and json.dumps() and receive errors. Here's the code,

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import json
import xmltodict
import subprocess
import os
import uuid
import requests
import json

# Generate a presigned URL for S3 Object
def get_presigned_url(expiration, objBucket, objKey):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', 'us-east-1', config=Config(s3={'addressing_style': 'virtual'}))
    Params={
        'Bucket': objBucket,
        'Key': objKey
    }
    print ('CORE:: Media Evaluator:: Bucket Name: ' + objBucket)
    print ('CORE:: Media Evaluator:: Object Key: ' + objKey)
    try:
        response = s3.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params, ExpiresIn=expiration)
        print('this is the response !!!!!!!!!', response)
    except ClientError as e:
        print (e)
        raise
        return None
    return response

# Get MD5 from S3 Object Tag
def get_md5_from_objectTag(objBucket, objKey):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', 'us-east-1', config=Config(s3={'addressing_style': 'virtual'}))
    response = s3.get_object_tagging(
        Bucket=objBucket,
        Key=objKey
    )
    for tag in response['TagSet']:
        if tag['Key'] == 'MD5':
            md5 = tag['Value']
    return md5

# Evaluate the media using MediaInfo
def get_mediainfo(presignedURL):
    print("presignedURL !!!!!!!!!!!!!", presignedURL)
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(['./mediainfo', '--full', '--output=JSON', presignedURL], shell=False, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        #  subprocess.check_output(["./mediainfo", "--full", "--output=JSON", presignedURL], stdin=None, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)    
        print("this si the output !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", output) 
        json_output = json.loads(output)
        print("this is the JOSN output!!!!!!", json_output)
        # Prepare the short media analysis JSON
        json_track = json_output['media']
        for f in json_track['track']:
            if f['@type'] == 'General':
                wrapper = f['Format']
            
            if f['@type'] == 'Video':
                wrapperType = f['Format_Profile']
                codec = f['Format']
                bitRate = f['BitRate']
                #frameRate = f['FrameRate']
                #som = f['TimeCode_FirstFrame']
                width = f['Width']
                height = f['Height']
                #framecount = f['FrameCount']
            #if f['@type'] == 'Other' and f['Type'] == 'Time code':
                #som = f['TimeCode_FirstFrame']
        mediaResult = {
            "Wrapper": wrapper + wrapperType,
            "Codec": codec,
            "BitRate": bitRate,
            #"FrameRate": frameRate,
            #"SOM": som,
            "Resolution": width + 'X' + height,
            #"FrameCount": framecount
        }
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        raise
        return None
    return mediaResult

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("this is the event !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", event)
    bucketName = event['bucketName']
    objectName = event['objectKey']
    signed_url = get_presigned_url(3600, bucketName, objectName)
    print ('CORE:: Media Evaluator:: Presigned URL: ' + signed_url)
    mediaAnalysis = get_mediainfo(signed_url)
    print('CORE:: Media Evaluator:: Parsed Media Analysis: ' + json.dumps(mediaAnalysis, indent=4))
    #md5 = get_md5_from_objectTag(bucketName, objectName)
    #print('CORE:: Media Evaluator:: MD5 Value from Object Tag: ' + md5)
    ingestData = {
        "MediaEvaluation": mediaAnalysis,
        #"MD5": md5,
        "AssetID": objectName.partition(".")[0],
        "AssetUID": uuid.uuid4().hex,
        "Bucket": bucketName,
        "ObjectKey": objectName
    } 
    print('this is ingestData !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!', ingestData)
    print('this is mediaAnalysis !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!', mediaAnalysis)

    #ingestDataJson = json.dumps(ingestData)
    #mediaAnalysisJson = json.dumps(mediaAnalysis)

    dataNotFake = { 's3url': ingestData.Bucket + '.s3.amazonaws.com/' + ingestData.objectKey, 
 'Codec': mediaAnalysis.Codec, 'resolution': mediaAnalysis.Resolution}

    r = requests.post(url ='<mongobdAtlasUrlConnectStringHere>', data = dataNotFake)
    
    return ingestData
```

what I am sending the Lambda is,

```
{
  "bucketName": "<s3-bucket-name>",
  "objectKey": "<video-file-name>"
}
```

edit:
the initial response

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'str' object has no attribute 'Bucket'",
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/mediaEvaluator.py\", line 107, in lambda_handler\n    dataNotFake = { 's3url': ingestDataJson.Bucket + '.s3.amazonaws.com/' + ingestDataJson.objectKey, 'Codec': mediaAnalysisJson.Codec, 'resolution': mediaAnalysisJson.Resolution}\n"
  ]
}
```

and, then the logs

```
7c4Uwzk422qMqIJfcFOZr6kwDasq3AEIy%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAAGgw2MTYwODIzMjAyOTEiDHJGza1WClZUa%2BZKEyqwAWPyeYiNirreNeRtXlelQjCxUnEj3HMZiMF2UlPLpzwY3RRNo5LBpieIuIRUm7HtbWqXp19lDsUBHiGSoZqmNW5i5EN5nTPe6c6LNdKYFXYutvd4X1dsVEij8srY0DW%2FjBpiZxGt3DlhLWiDtoA8EjgXEe4JcpvU6Z9EpJeotjFhBzfe%2BM7xoPYE%2BoYS4ipx0nyntPQ4Qia1Cdh9LBwsHbcPL59JeI27lVmkggCFevZXMLqPzIEGOuABHPLi%2B3fu1bxwoDJYaA0HOwnAbF%2FncPMWpIR9NATDHyq%2B6BbaOxFAygyNXC%2FAjjqCEOezv1yfZ0VCMAP9i0Wi%2BBqgL8s4Qbuwk1PdgSfZdwqxrSOynSeX6s7Z5au9QYn%2BY%2F5upVr%2F5dt6Q8veRAWuqEQx4muzEix0jorBm4j1KAmuTYfv3A71Hv9YfhMmbR6h4XZv1U8nQpqNJNIJ%2FC%2BBBbRuXDWMhbfnK6IiXw9e3VWqQa7Esjj0WqHgOZ1wWGLZvqqy5Re%2Bm%2BF9eFdE%2F3mUv516aeU31eZ0gkHxnZGZ6HY%3D&Expires=1613960653', 'track': [{'@type': 'General', 'ID': '1', 'VideoCount': '1', 'MenuCount': '1', 'FileExtension': 'mpg?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAY64K6FOR54JVBB5W&Signature=b16%2BkSWWYrrZvBlYA5tvs7DsqO4%3D&x-amz-security-token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEML%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQCyP7t3a9Y6%2F4brzVhIOH5GEMpkargZlHCnX55tbiJKwQIgdBNqAwljhCiLZbf%2F7c4Uwzk422qMqIJfcFOZr6kwDasq3AEIy%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAAGgw2MTYwODIzMjAyOTEiDHJGza1WClZUa%2BZKEyqwAWPyeYiNirreNeRtXlelQjCxUnEj3HMZiMF2UlPLpzwY3RRNo5LBpieIuIRUm7HtbWqXp19lDsUBHiGSoZqmNW5i5EN5nTPe6c6LNdKYFXYutvd4X1dsVEij8srY0DW%2FjBpiZxGt3DlhLWiDtoA8EjgXEe4JcpvU6Z9EpJeotjFhBzfe%2BM7xoPYE%2BoYS4ipx0nyntPQ4Qia1Cdh9LBwsHbcPL59JeI27lVmkggCFevZXMLqPzIEGOuABHPLi%2B3fu1bxwoDJYaA0HOwnAbF%2FncPMWpIR9NATDHyq%2B6BbaOxFAygyNXC%2FAjjqCEOezv1yfZ0VCMAP9i0Wi%2BBqgL8s4Qbuwk1PdgSfZdwqxrSOynSeX6s7Z5au9QYn%2BY%2F5upVr%2F5dt6Q8veRAWuqEQx4muzEix0jorBm4j1KAmuTYfv3A71Hv9YfhMmbR6h4XZv1U8nQpqNJNIJ%2FC%2BBBbRuXDWMhbfnK6IiXw9e3VWqQa7Esjj0WqHgOZ1wWGLZvqqy5Re%2Bm%2BF9eFdE%2F3mUv516aeU31eZ0gkHxnZGZ6HY%3D&Expires=1613960653', 'Format': 'MPEG-TS', 'FileSize': '102004664', 'Duration': '200.236328125', 'OverallBitRate_Mode': 'CBR', 'OverallBitRate': '4075040', 'StreamSize': '7646822', 'extra': {'OverallBitRate_Precision_Min': '4075030', 'OverallBitRate_Precision_Max': '4075051', 'FileExtension_Invalid': 'ts m2t m2s m4t m4s tmf ts tp trp ty'}}, {'@type': 'Video', 'StreamOrder': '0-0', 'ID': '481', 'MenuID': '1', 'Format': 'AVC', 'Format_Profile': 'Main', 'Format_Level': '4.1', 'Format_Settings_CABAC': 'Yes', 'Format_Settings_RefFrames': '1', 'Format_Settings_GOP': 'M=1, N=15', 'CodecID': '27', 'Duration': '194.867', 'BitRate': '3873733', 'Width': '1280', 'Height': '720', 'Sampled_Width': '1280', 'Sampled_Height': '720', 'PixelAspectRatio': '1.000', 'DisplayAspectRatio': '1.778', 'ColorSpace': 'YUV', 'ChromaSubsampling': '4:2:0', 'BitDepth': '8', 'ScanType': 'Progressive', 'Delay': '10.000000', 'StreamSize': '94357842'}, {'@type': 'Menu', 'StreamOrder': '0', 'ID': '480', 'MenuID': '1', 'Format': 'AVC / KLV', 'Duration': '200.236328125', 'Delay': '0.001107222', 'List_StreamKind': '1 / ', 'List_StreamPos': '0 / ', 'extra': {'pointer_field': '0', 'section_length': '55'}}]}}
CORE:: Media Evaluator:: Parsed Media Analysis: {
    "Wrapper": "MPEG-TSMain",
    "Codec": "AVC",
    "BitRate": "3873733",
    "Resolution": "1280X720"
}
this is ingestData !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! {'MediaEvaluation': {'Wrapper': 'MPEG-TSMain', 'Codec': 'AVC', 'BitRate': '3873733', 'Resolution': '1280X720'}, 'AssetID': 'Day Flight', 'AssetUID': 'cb0651e1151f41a5a890425d41bda3cb', 'Bucket': 'video-uploads-94viwznlhm88', 'ObjectKey': 'Day Flight.mpg'}
this is mediaAnalysis !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! {'Wrapper': 'MPEG-TSMain', 'Codec': 'AVC', 'BitRate': '3873733', 'Resolution': '1280X720'}
[ERROR] AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Bucket'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/mediaEvaluator.py", line 107, in lambda_handler
    dataNotFake = { 's3url': ingestDataJson.Bucket + '.s3.amazonaws.com/' + ingestDataJson.objectKey, 'Codec': mediaAnalysisJson.Codec, 'resolution': mediaAnalysisJson.Resolution}
END RequestId: bfcf3bb8-d709-44c5-9e42-8c7a6a31a879
REPORT RequestId: bfcf3bb8-d709-44c5-9e42-8c7a6a31a879  Duration: 6679.29 ms    Billed Duration: 6680 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 104 MB Init Duration: 382.19 ms
```

Comment: can you print the event and share the output which is received inside the lambda

Comment: Sure, see above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here

> dataNotFake = { 's3url': ingestData.Bucket + '.s3.amazonaws.com/' + ingestData.objectKey,

considering these

```
ingestData = {'MediaEvaluation': {'Wrapper': 'MPEG-TSMain',
  'Codec': 'AVC',
  'BitRate': '3873733',
  'Resolution': '1280X720'},
 'AssetID': 'Day Flight',
 'AssetUID': 'cb0651e1151f41a5a890425d41bda3cb',
 'Bucket': 'video-uploads-94viwznlhm88',
 'ObjectKey': 'Day Flight.mpg'}
```

```
mediaAnalysis = {
'Wrapper': 'MPEG-TSMain', 'Codec': 'AVC', 'BitRate': '3873733', 'Resolution': '1280X720'}
```

You should use something like this

```
dataNotFake = { 
's3url': f'{ingestData["Bucket"]}.s3.amazonaws.com/{ingestData["ObjectKey"]}', 
'Codec': mediaAnalysis['Codec'],
'resolution': mediaAnalysis['Resolution']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I still cannot drill into ingestData, but I managed to avoid the issue by passing bucketName and objectName to create the s3 URL to link to the upload data in mongo and passing the whole mediaAnalysis to mongo.

```
  dataNotFake = { "s3url": bucketName + '.s3.amazonaws.com/' + objectName, "mediaAnalysis": mediaAnalysis}
```